# Table styles disappear when updating content

Tags: code, table

The tables on my website all have custom code for their style. Lately, when I go in to edit the content of the table (not the code), the style will completely disappear on the webpage when I update it. The only thing I change/touch is the words within the table, I don't change any of the code, but as soon as I hit the update button, the style (table colour, borders, etc.) disappear. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to add some styles instead of inline-styles (I'm inferring that's what they are). It's possible the WYSIWYG editor is stripping certain tags on save. Alternatively, edit your code in the HTML version instead of the visual editor and see if that makes a difference. Make sure to save before switching back to the visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress in some cases automatically adds code tags ( like p tags and changes code structure ) when you edit content in "Visual" mode.

Try to make changes and save in "Text" mode ( as Greg said in comment ).

Comment: I have been making the changes in the text mode, and for some reason the style still disappears :(

Comment: You've probably already accidentally changed code, it's hard to say anything else without seeing the code